# how to update a value inside the if condition

Tags: if-statement, angular, typescript, ionic2

i have situation where `checknotificationObj="true"` (i.e `_this.noteValue="ture"` ) as you can see below.

now how to make that `_this.noteValue =false` when it enters the if condtion in .ts . this same visiversa for else part

I am new to angular2 help me please

```
let checkNotifictionObj = _this.noteValue;
     if(checkNotifictionObj){
        notificationDetails={
          notification:"flase"
        };
       _this.noteValue="false";
     }
     else{
       notificationDetails={
         notification:"true"
       };
       _this.noteValue="true";
     }
```

> i am not able to update checkNotifictionObj `true` to `false` and `false` to `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do it as below :

```
let checkNotifictionObj:boolean = _this.noteValue; // _this.noteValue must be of boolean type
if(checkNotifictionObj){
  notificationDetails={
    notification : false
  };
  _this.noteValue = false;
} else {
  notificationDetails={
    notification : true
  };
  _this.noteValue = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is:

1. If `_this.noteValue` is `true`:

   - Set

     ```
     notificationDetails = {
       notification : false
     }
     ```
   - Set `_this.noteValue` to `false`.
2. If `_this.noteValue` is `false`:

   - Set

     ```
     notificationDetails = {
       notification : true
     }
     ```
   - Set `_this.noteValue` to `true`.

An easier way to do it would be just:

```
_this.noteValue = !_this.noteValue; // If _this.noteValue is equal to true, now it will be set to false. If it's false, it will be set to true.

notificationDetails = {
  notification: _this.noteValue
};
```

That way you don't need an `if/else`.